# Why can't I edit the question that I have answered?

Tags: support, questions

As far as I understand I can suggest edits for any post. (is that right?)
But I have answered a question and the code that is posted is not formated. I want to format it but my edit button is greyed out. Why is that?

Edit: this is happening on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30866217/for-loop-python-does-not-go-over-all-objects/30866297#30866297)

Comment: they are all grey and look disabled on my screen.  did you try clicking it?

Comment: On what question? (Link please)

Comment: @Plutonix yes and it is not working.

Comment: It says `edit (1)`.  Note the (1), it means that there is already a pending edit in the queue.  Probably to fix the formatting.  You can't propose an edit until that one is dispatched.

Comment: @HansPassant I can't see the `(1)` because I don't have enough rep.

Comment: The pending edit was approved just now. You should be able to suggest a edit, now.

Comment: I can see more changes are needed, but since you're going in there anyway, quicker to approve and let you rip on it. Bad of me, I know.

Comment: I see I wasn't the only one, @Cerbrus. Just in case anyone looks that particular review, please remember that the figures are (still, for more than 6-8 weeks) entirely busted. 350-some approvals for me *could* be correct, and I have over 1200 edit reviews completed. So slightly more than five rejections.